# How do I extend div beyond viewport in CSS?

Tags: html, css, scroll, viewport

What I'm trying to do is have a div that is directly in the body extend beyond the viewport when I overscroll downwards. Right now, when I scroll down at the bottom of the page, the content kind of "overscrolls" revealing the body's background. I want the div's background to be visible there.

I searched for a solution for hours, but couldn't find anything so I tried setting the margin-bottom to a negative value, but to no avail.

Here's the code with sample text and with a style tag instead of a seperate stylesheet file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style> 
            body{
                background-color: red;
            }
            .content {
                margin: 2% 10%;
                margin-bottom: -1000px;
                padding: 5% 5%;
                background-color: #404040;
                color: lightgrey;
                overflow: visible;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Content</p>
            <p>spanning</p>
            <p>many</p>
            <p>many</p>
            <p>many</p>
            <p>many</p>
            <p>many</p>
            <p>many</p>
            <p>many</p>
            <p>many</p>
            <p>many</p>
            <p>many</p>
            <p>many</p>
            <p>many</p>
            <p>many</p>
            <p>many</p>
            <p>many</p>
            <p>lines</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue turned out to be only present when scrolling with a touchpad or touchscreen on Windows 11 in Firefox version 116.0.2 or possibly earlier versions as well

Edit: it can be turned off in about:config by setting apz.overscroll.enabled to false

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to remove the body's default margin and then explicitly provide div a margin on each side like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style> 
            body{
                background-color: red;
                margin: 0;
            }
            .content {
                margin: 2% 10% 0 10%;
                padding: 5% 5%;
                background-color: #404040;
                color: lightgrey;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Content</p>
            <p>spanning</p>
            <p>many</p>
            <p>many</p>
            <p>many</p>
            <p>many</p>
            <p>many</p>
            <p>many</p>
            <p>many</p>
            <p>many</p>
            <p>many</p>
            <p>many</p>
            <p>many</p>
            <p>many</p>
            <p>many</p>
            <p>many</p>
            <p>many</p>
            <p>lines</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and in your case, you don't need the overflow in the div as you want your body to scroll here is the updated code.
Hopefully, it will fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of easy options, the first is to use a pseudo-element to carry the background-colour (or background-image) as below:

```css
:root {
  --main-inline-size: 80%;
  --main-max-inline-size: 1200px;
  --main-min-inline-size: 20rem;
  --spacing: 0.5rem;
}

*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  block-size: 100vh;
  font-family: system-ui;
  padding-block: 12rem;
  
  /* the background for the page: */
  background-color: lightpink;
}

menu,
ol,
ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

main {
  inline-size: clamp(var(--main-min-inline-size), var(--main-inline-size), var(--main-max-inline-size));
  margin-inline: auto;
  min-block-size: 100%;
  padding: var(--spacing);
  
  /* to have the absolutely-positioned pseudo-element positioned in relation to this
     element: */
  position: relative;
}

main::before {
  /* the content property must have a value set for the pseudo-element to
     be rendered to the page: */
  content: '';
  /* we're using absolute positioning: */
  position: absolute;
  /* using inset to position the top, and bottom, edges of the
     element 50vh above and below the edges of the parent element;
     and zero distance from either the left or right edge:
     */
  inset: -50vh 0;
  /* the background-color: */
  background-color: #ddf9;
  /* using a negative z-index to position the background behind the content of
     the element: */
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <header>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor</h1>
    <p>Arbitrary header tagline text</p>
  </header>
  <section>
    <h2>Ipsum dolor</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque porro accusantium omnis cum harum, asperiores tempora cumque itaque quidem possimus sapiente nihil, aliquam error obcaecati quam ea totam fugiat impedit suscipit, fuga dolores eveniet odit? Maxime necessitatibus accusamus dolores ea optio quae quaerat iure error. Inventore, cum, ratione. In perspiciatis, saepe. Perspiciatis quibusdam assumenda dolor, ut quae, molestiae deserunt vitae? Accusantium in nulla odio sint commodi eum reprehenderit quis iusto maiores, autem, tempora ut enim praesentium repudiandae vel magni omnis. Repudiandae veritatis dolorem libero minima nam, tempora quae ex commodi, eligendi placeat rem accusamus repellendus in sequi fugit nesciunt excepturi. Natus numquam dolorum aliquam atque non neque voluptatum illum quidem quod adipisci consequuntur cum similique, saepe doloremque est modi. Odio eum ex sunt qui nihil ipsum fugit quidem est mollitia necessitatibus accusamus cumque tempore illo omnis, commodi delectus tenetur excepturi, voluptas eligendi rem! Culpa, possimus repudiandae harum esse, corrupti sunt nemo ratione est sequi doloremque velit provident neque quam impedit. Esse placeat libero distinctio, temporibus deleniti dolor recusandae aliquid tempora. Maxime nesciunt natus harum nulla aspernatur dolorem, impedit nemo pariatur et consequuntur, quasi sapiente velit neque dolores. Expedita adipisci dolores aliquam quo, provident iure, ea nostrum, laboriosam a esse dolorum enim aut atque, sed voluptas dolorem! Voluptatem similique rerum error quas perferendis et, obcaecati reiciendis nemo, debitis. Saepe nostrum veniam tenetur recusandae! Quam nesciunt cum, atque id ipsa quisquam rerum aut, voluptatum iusto odio consectetur magni omnis, labore! Laboriosam et vero, ab officiis nostrum obcaecati? Dolorem est optio consequatur magnam, dignissimos, dolor aliquam maxime rem. Modi vitae doloribus tempore voluptatibus minus, deserunt quae a blanditiis dolorum minima, sint vel sed, autem possimus delectus fugit accusantium ducimus! Magni doloremque, maiores eius nesciunt est tempore quod deserunt sapiente sit illo minus modi rem dolor! Doloremque aspernatur quaerat, aperiam vero sapiente voluptatem numquam. Ipsa veniam quos doloribus error veritatis nam ratione alias, corporis nostrum nihil dicta delectus molestias deleniti numquam explicabo earum porro repellendus asperiores inventore! Deserunt debitis ipsum ipsa numquam veritatis, dolore modi sint quibusdam aperiam possimus at ea adipisci itaque nihil sequi repudiandae, iusto soluta distinctio ad minima nam quasi consequuntur earum? Voluptas sed accusamus laborum dignissimos iure quod, tempore perspiciatis impedit eius libero sunt voluptate autem unde numquam architecto, voluptatibus aliquid natus praesentium, aspernatur similique ipsam minima ea ratione. Velit dolor ut accusamus reiciendis nam aliquid, aspernatur, architecto, eum consectetur amet corrupti asperiores tenetur, numquam. Est quaerat reiciendis animi voluptatum voluptatibus eius neque maxime corporis, unde illum impedit quae aspernatur aliquid error dignissimos tenetur ipsum vitae earum nemo molestiae quas facere magnam. Accusantium officia, odio illo! Iusto velit inventore illo, distinctio, et repellat, aut possimus consequatur dolor commodi architecto. Possimus unde dolores nulla, ullam culpa, obcaecati nostrum neque illo doloremque?</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Dolor sit</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque porro accusantium omnis cum harum, asperiores tempora cumque itaque quidem possimus sapiente nihil, aliquam error obcaecati quam ea totam fugiat impedit suscipit, fuga dolores eveniet odit? Maxime necessitatibus accusamus dolores ea optio quae quaerat iure error. Inventore, cum, ratione. In perspiciatis, saepe. Perspiciatis quibusdam assumenda dolor, ut quae, molestiae deserunt vitae? Accusantium in nulla odio sint commodi eum reprehenderit quis iusto maiores, autem, tempora ut enim praesentium repudiandae vel magni omnis. Repudiandae veritatis dolorem libero minima nam, tempora quae ex commodi, eligendi placeat rem accusamus repellendus in sequi fugit nesciunt excepturi. Natus numquam dolorum aliquam atque non neque voluptatum illum quidem quod adipisci consequuntur cum similique, saepe doloremque est modi. Odio eum ex sunt qui nihil ipsum fugit quidem est mollitia necessitatibus accusamus cumque tempore illo omnis, commodi delectus tenetur excepturi, voluptas eligendi rem! Culpa, possimus repudiandae harum esse, corrupti sunt nemo ratione est sequi doloremque velit provident neque quam impedit. Esse placeat libero distinctio, temporibus deleniti dolor recusandae aliquid tempora. Maxime nesciunt natus harum nulla aspernatur dolorem, impedit nemo pariatur et consequuntur, quasi sapiente velit neque dolores. Expedita adipisci dolores aliquam quo, provident iure, ea nostrum, laboriosam a esse dolorum enim aut atque, sed voluptas dolorem! Voluptatem similique rerum error quas perferendis et, obcaecati reiciendis nemo, debitis. Saepe nostrum veniam tenetur recusandae! Quam nesciunt cum, atque id ipsa quisquam rerum aut, voluptatum iusto odio consectetur magni omnis, labore! Laboriosam et vero, ab officiis nostrum obcaecati? Dolorem est optio consequatur magnam, dignissimos, dolor aliquam maxime rem. Modi vitae doloribus tempore voluptatibus minus, deserunt quae a blanditiis dolorum minima, sint vel sed, autem possimus delectus fugit accusantium ducimus! Magni doloremque, maiores eius nesciunt est tempore quod deserunt sapiente sit illo minus modi rem dolor! Doloremque aspernatur quaerat, aperiam vero sapiente voluptatem numquam. Ipsa veniam quos doloribus error veritatis nam ratione alias, corporis nostrum nihil dicta delectus molestias deleniti numquam explicabo earum porro repellendus asperiores inventore! Deserunt debitis ipsum ipsa numquam veritatis, dolore modi sint quibusdam aperiam possimus at ea adipisci itaque nihil sequi repudiandae, iusto soluta distinctio ad minima nam quasi consequuntur earum? Voluptas sed accusamus laborum dignissimos iure quod, tempore perspiciatis impedit eius libero sunt voluptate autem unde numquam architecto, voluptatibus aliquid natus praesentium, aspernatur similique ipsam minima ea ratione. Velit dolor ut accusamus reiciendis nam aliquid, aspernatur, architecto, eum consectetur amet corrupti asperiores tenetur, numquam. Est quaerat reiciendis animi voluptatum voluptatibus eius neque maxime corporis, unde illum impedit quae aspernatur aliquid error dignissimos tenetur ipsum vitae earum nemo molestiae quas facere magnam. Accusantium officia, odio illo! Iusto velit inventore illo, distinctio, et repellat, aut possimus consequatur dolor commodi architecto. Possimus unde dolores nulla, ullam culpa, obcaecati nostrum neque illo doloremque?</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Sit anet</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque porro accusantium omnis cum harum, asperiores tempora cumque itaque quidem possimus sapiente nihil, aliquam error obcaecati quam ea totam fugiat impedit suscipit, fuga dolores eveniet odit? Maxime necessitatibus accusamus dolores ea optio quae quaerat iure error. Inventore, cum, ratione. In perspiciatis, saepe. Perspiciatis quibusdam assumenda dolor, ut quae, molestiae deserunt vitae? Accusantium in nulla odio sint commodi eum reprehenderit quis iusto maiores, autem, tempora ut enim praesentium repudiandae vel magni omnis. Repudiandae veritatis dolorem libero minima nam, tempora quae ex commodi, eligendi placeat rem accusamus repellendus in sequi fugit nesciunt excepturi. Natus numquam dolorum aliquam atque non neque voluptatum illum quidem quod adipisci consequuntur cum similique, saepe doloremque est modi. Odio eum ex sunt qui nihil ipsum fugit quidem est mollitia necessitatibus accusamus cumque tempore illo omnis, commodi delectus tenetur excepturi, voluptas eligendi rem! Culpa, possimus repudiandae harum esse, corrupti sunt nemo ratione est sequi doloremque velit provident neque quam impedit. Esse placeat libero distinctio, temporibus deleniti dolor recusandae aliquid tempora. Maxime nesciunt natus harum nulla aspernatur dolorem, impedit nemo pariatur et consequuntur, quasi sapiente velit neque dolores. Expedita adipisci dolores aliquam quo, provident iure, ea nostrum, laboriosam a esse dolorum enim aut atque, sed voluptas dolorem! Voluptatem similique rerum error quas perferendis et, obcaecati reiciendis nemo, debitis. Saepe nostrum veniam tenetur recusandae! Quam nesciunt cum, atque id ipsa quisquam rerum aut, voluptatum iusto odio consectetur magni omnis, labore! Laboriosam et vero, ab officiis nostrum obcaecati? Dolorem est optio consequatur magnam, dignissimos, dolor aliquam maxime rem. Modi vitae doloribus tempore voluptatibus minus, deserunt quae a blanditiis dolorum minima, sint vel sed, autem possimus delectus fugit accusantium ducimus! Magni doloremque, maiores eius nesciunt est tempore quod deserunt sapiente sit illo minus modi rem dolor! Doloremque aspernatur quaerat, aperiam vero sapiente voluptatem numquam. Ipsa veniam quos doloribus error veritatis nam ratione alias, corporis nostrum nihil dicta delectus molestias deleniti numquam explicabo earum porro repellendus asperiores inventore! Deserunt debitis ipsum ipsa numquam veritatis, dolore modi sint quibusdam aperiam possimus at ea adipisci itaque nihil sequi repudiandae, iusto soluta distinctio ad minima nam quasi consequuntur earum? Voluptas sed accusamus laborum dignissimos iure quod, tempore perspiciatis impedit eius libero sunt voluptate autem unde numquam architecto, voluptatibus aliquid natus praesentium, aspernatur similique ipsam minima ea ratione. Velit dolor ut accusamus reiciendis nam aliquid, aspernatur, architecto, eum consectetur amet corrupti asperiores tenetur, numquam. Est quaerat reiciendis animi voluptatum voluptatibus eius neque maxime corporis, unde illum impedit quae aspernatur aliquid error dignissimos tenetur ipsum vitae earum nemo molestiae quas facere magnam. Accusantium officia, odio illo! Iusto velit inventore illo, distinctio, et repellat, aut possimus consequatur dolor commodi architecto. Possimus unde dolores nulla, ullam culpa, obcaecati nostrum neque illo doloremque?</p>
  </section>
</main>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/r7xznbkc/).

Alternatively, we could use CSS custom properties and simply apply a background-gradient to the `<body>` element:

```css
:root {
  --bleedColor: hsl(300deg 90% 85% / 1);
  --inlineBorderSize: 0.2rem;
  --inlineInset: 10rem;
  /*
    if you want the 'bleed' to be at the edges of the content of
    the relevant element, then the padding of that element can be
    listed below; if none is supplied the default value of 0px
    will be used: */
  --inlinePadding: 0px;
}

*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  --_inlineStart: calc(var(--inlineInset) + var(--inlineBorderSize) + var(--inlinePadding) - var(--inlineBorderSize));
  --_inlineEnd: calc(100% - var(--_inlineStart));
  background-color: lightpink;
  background-image: linear-gradient( 90deg, transparent 0 var(--_inlineStart), var(--bleedColor) var(--_inlineStart) var(--_inlineEnd), transparent var(--_inlineEnd));
  block-size: 100vh;
  font-family: system-ui;
}

menu,
ol,
ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

main {
  border: var(--inlineBorderSize) solid currentColor;
  min-block-size: 100%;
  margin-block: 12rem;
  margin-inline: var(--inlineInset);
  padding-inline: var(--inlinePadding);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <header>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor</h1>
    <p>Arbitrary header tagline text</p>
  </header>
  <section>
    <h2>Ipsum dolor</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque porro accusantium omnis cum harum, asperiores tempora cumque itaque quidem possimus sapiente nihil, aliquam error obcaecati quam ea totam fugiat impedit suscipit, fuga dolores eveniet
      odit? Maxime necessitatibus accusamus dolores ea optio quae quaerat iure error. Inventore, cum, ratione. In perspiciatis, saepe. Perspiciatis quibusdam assumenda dolor, ut quae, molestiae deserunt vitae? Accusantium in nulla odio sint commodi eum
      reprehenderit quis iusto maiores, autem, tempora ut enim praesentium repudiandae vel magni omnis. Repudiandae veritatis dolorem libero minima nam, tempora quae ex commodi, eligendi placeat rem accusamus repellendus in sequi fugit nesciunt excepturi.
      Natus numquam dolorum aliquam atque non neque voluptatum illum quidem quod adipisci consequuntur cum similique, saepe doloremque est modi. Odio eum ex sunt qui nihil ipsum fugit quidem est mollitia necessitatibus accusamus cumque tempore illo omnis,
      commodi delectus tenetur excepturi, voluptas eligendi rem! Culpa, possimus repudiandae harum esse, corrupti sunt nemo ratione est sequi doloremque velit provident neque quam impedit. Esse placeat libero distinctio, temporibus deleniti dolor recusandae
      aliquid tempora. Maxime nesciunt natus harum nulla aspernatur dolorem, impedit nemo pariatur et consequuntur, quasi sapiente velit neque dolores. Expedita adipisci dolores aliquam quo, provident iure, ea nostrum, laboriosam a esse dolorum enim aut
      atque, sed voluptas dolorem! Voluptatem similique rerum error quas perferendis et, obcaecati reiciendis nemo, debitis. Saepe nostrum veniam tenetur recusandae! Quam nesciunt cum, atque id ipsa quisquam rerum aut, voluptatum iusto odio consectetur
      magni omnis, labore! Laboriosam et vero, ab officiis nostrum obcaecati? Dolorem est optio consequatur magnam, dignissimos, dolor aliquam maxime rem. Modi vitae doloribus tempore voluptatibus minus, deserunt quae a blanditiis dolorum minima, sint
      vel sed, autem possimus delectus fugit accusantium ducimus! Magni doloremque, maiores eius nesciunt est tempore quod deserunt sapiente sit illo minus modi rem dolor! Doloremque aspernatur quaerat, aperiam vero sapiente voluptatem numquam. Ipsa veniam
      quos doloribus error veritatis nam ratione alias, corporis nostrum nihil dicta delectus molestias deleniti numquam explicabo earum porro repellendus asperiores inventore! Deserunt debitis ipsum ipsa numquam veritatis, dolore modi sint quibusdam
      aperiam possimus at ea adipisci itaque nihil sequi repudiandae, iusto soluta distinctio ad minima nam quasi consequuntur earum? Voluptas sed accusamus laborum dignissimos iure quod, tempore perspiciatis impedit eius libero sunt voluptate autem unde
      numquam architecto, voluptatibus aliquid natus praesentium, aspernatur similique ipsam minima ea ratione. Velit dolor ut accusamus reiciendis nam aliquid, aspernatur, architecto, eum consectetur amet corrupti asperiores tenetur, numquam. Est quaerat
      reiciendis animi voluptatum voluptatibus eius neque maxime corporis, unde illum impedit quae aspernatur aliquid error dignissimos tenetur ipsum vitae earum nemo molestiae quas facere magnam. Accusantium officia, odio illo! Iusto velit inventore
      illo, distinctio, et repellat, aut possimus consequatur dolor commodi architecto. Possimus unde dolores nulla, ullam culpa, obcaecati nostrum neque illo doloremque?</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Dolor sit</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque porro accusantium omnis cum harum, asperiores tempora cumque itaque quidem possimus sapiente nihil, aliquam error obcaecati quam ea totam fugiat impedit suscipit, fuga dolores eveniet
      odit? Maxime necessitatibus accusamus dolores ea optio quae quaerat iure error. Inventore, cum, ratione. In perspiciatis, saepe. Perspiciatis quibusdam assumenda dolor, ut quae, molestiae deserunt vitae? Accusantium in nulla odio sint commodi eum
      reprehenderit quis iusto maiores, autem, tempora ut enim praesentium repudiandae vel magni omnis. Repudiandae veritatis dolorem libero minima nam, tempora quae ex commodi, eligendi placeat rem accusamus repellendus in sequi fugit nesciunt excepturi.
      Natus numquam dolorum aliquam atque non neque voluptatum illum quidem quod adipisci consequuntur cum similique, saepe doloremque est modi. Odio eum ex sunt qui nihil ipsum fugit quidem est mollitia necessitatibus accusamus cumque tempore illo omnis,
      commodi delectus tenetur excepturi, voluptas eligendi rem! Culpa, possimus repudiandae harum esse, corrupti sunt nemo ratione est sequi doloremque velit provident neque quam impedit. Esse placeat libero distinctio, temporibus deleniti dolor recusandae
      aliquid tempora. Maxime nesciunt natus harum nulla aspernatur dolorem, impedit nemo pariatur et consequuntur, quasi sapiente velit neque dolores. Expedita adipisci dolores aliquam quo, provident iure, ea nostrum, laboriosam a esse dolorum enim aut
      atque, sed voluptas dolorem! Voluptatem similique rerum error quas perferendis et, obcaecati reiciendis nemo, debitis. Saepe nostrum veniam tenetur recusandae! Quam nesciunt cum, atque id ipsa quisquam rerum aut, voluptatum iusto odio consectetur
      magni omnis, labore! Laboriosam et vero, ab officiis nostrum obcaecati? Dolorem est optio consequatur magnam, dignissimos, dolor aliquam maxime rem. Modi vitae doloribus tempore voluptatibus minus, deserunt quae a blanditiis dolorum minima, sint
      vel sed, autem possimus delectus fugit accusantium ducimus! Magni doloremque, maiores eius nesciunt est tempore quod deserunt sapiente sit illo minus modi rem dolor! Doloremque aspernatur quaerat, aperiam vero sapiente voluptatem numquam. Ipsa veniam
      quos doloribus error veritatis nam ratione alias, corporis nostrum nihil dicta delectus molestias deleniti numquam explicabo earum porro repellendus asperiores inventore! Deserunt debitis ipsum ipsa numquam veritatis, dolore modi sint quibusdam
      aperiam possimus at ea adipisci itaque nihil sequi repudiandae, iusto soluta distinctio ad minima nam quasi consequuntur earum? Voluptas sed accusamus laborum dignissimos iure quod, tempore perspiciatis impedit eius libero sunt voluptate autem unde
      numquam architecto, voluptatibus aliquid natus praesentium, aspernatur similique ipsam minima ea ratione. Velit dolor ut accusamus reiciendis nam aliquid, aspernatur, architecto, eum consectetur amet corrupti asperiores tenetur, numquam. Est quaerat
      reiciendis animi voluptatum voluptatibus eius neque maxime corporis, unde illum impedit quae aspernatur aliquid error dignissimos tenetur ipsum vitae earum nemo molestiae quas facere magnam. Accusantium officia, odio illo! Iusto velit inventore
      illo, distinctio, et repellat, aut possimus consequatur dolor commodi architecto. Possimus unde dolores nulla, ullam culpa, obcaecati nostrum neque illo doloremque?</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Sit anet</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque porro accusantium omnis cum harum, asperiores tempora cumque itaque quidem possimus sapiente nihil, aliquam error obcaecati quam ea totam fugiat impedit suscipit, fuga dolores eveniet
      odit? Maxime necessitatibus accusamus dolores ea optio quae quaerat iure error. Inventore, cum, ratione. In perspiciatis, saepe. Perspiciatis quibusdam assumenda dolor, ut quae, molestiae deserunt vitae? Accusantium in nulla odio sint commodi eum
      reprehenderit quis iusto maiores, autem, tempora ut enim praesentium repudiandae vel magni omnis. Repudiandae veritatis dolorem libero minima nam, tempora quae ex commodi, eligendi placeat rem accusamus repellendus in sequi fugit nesciunt excepturi.
      Natus numquam dolorum aliquam atque non neque voluptatum illum quidem quod adipisci consequuntur cum similique, saepe doloremque est modi. Odio eum ex sunt qui nihil ipsum fugit quidem est mollitia necessitatibus accusamus cumque tempore illo omnis,
      commodi delectus tenetur excepturi, voluptas eligendi rem! Culpa, possimus repudiandae harum esse, corrupti sunt nemo ratione est sequi doloremque velit provident neque quam impedit. Esse placeat libero distinctio, temporibus deleniti dolor recusandae
      aliquid tempora. Maxime nesciunt natus harum nulla aspernatur dolorem, impedit nemo pariatur et consequuntur, quasi sapiente velit neque dolores. Expedita adipisci dolores aliquam quo, provident iure, ea nostrum, laboriosam a esse dolorum enim aut
      atque, sed voluptas dolorem! Voluptatem similique rerum error quas perferendis et, obcaecati reiciendis nemo, debitis. Saepe nostrum veniam tenetur recusandae! Quam nesciunt cum, atque id ipsa quisquam rerum aut, voluptatum iusto odio consectetur
      magni omnis, labore! Laboriosam et vero, ab officiis nostrum obcaecati? Dolorem est optio consequatur magnam, dignissimos, dolor aliquam maxime rem. Modi vitae doloribus tempore voluptatibus minus, deserunt quae a blanditiis dolorum minima, sint
      vel sed, autem possimus delectus fugit accusantium ducimus! Magni doloremque, maiores eius nesciunt est tempore quod deserunt sapiente sit illo minus modi rem dolor! Doloremque aspernatur quaerat, aperiam vero sapiente voluptatem numquam. Ipsa veniam
      quos doloribus error veritatis nam ratione alias, corporis nostrum nihil dicta delectus molestias deleniti numquam explicabo earum porro repellendus asperiores inventore! Deserunt debitis ipsum ipsa numquam veritatis, dolore modi sint quibusdam
      aperiam possimus at ea adipisci itaque nihil sequi repudiandae, iusto soluta distinctio ad minima nam quasi consequuntur earum? Voluptas sed accusamus laborum dignissimos iure quod, tempore perspiciatis impedit eius libero sunt voluptate autem unde
      numquam architecto, voluptatibus aliquid natus praesentium, aspernatur similique ipsam minima ea ratione. Velit dolor ut accusamus reiciendis nam aliquid, aspernatur, architecto, eum consectetur amet corrupti asperiores tenetur, numquam. Est quaerat
      reiciendis animi voluptatum voluptatibus eius neque maxime corporis, unde illum impedit quae aspernatur aliquid error dignissimos tenetur ipsum vitae earum nemo molestiae quas facere magnam. Accusantium officia, odio illo! Iusto velit inventore
      illo, distinctio, et repellat, aut possimus consequatur dolor commodi architecto. Possimus unde dolores nulla, ullam culpa, obcaecati nostrum neque illo doloremque?</p>
  </section>
</main>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/r7xznbkc/4/).

Comment: Hey there! Thank you for answering, but your solution still has the same issue. At least when run as a code snippet (https://imgur.com/a/ZxenEmG)

I'm starting to think it's a default behaviour with my browser (firefox)?

Comment: My own experience, from the first snippet here, doesn't seem to reproduce the issue you show: [img](https://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/linked/screenshot-SO-76889093-FF-on-Ubuntu.png).

Comment: Well, then it's either firefox or Windows 11 since it focuses on touch screen stuff? Anyways, thank you for the help! At least I don't have to worry about it anymore!

Comment: It's worth adding that the second snippet - which I've now edited to use a margin on the `<main>` rather than padding on the `<body>` - gives the following screenshot: [img](https://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/linked/screenshot-SO-76889093-FF-on-Ubuntu_2.png). Both screenshots were taken from Firefox 116, on Ubuntu; I don't know if that meaningfully helps you narrow down the scope of the problem. If you visit the snippets at JS Fiddle ([snippet 1](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/r7xznbkc/show), [snippet 2](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/r7xznbkc/4/show)) in full-screen, is there any difference?

Comment: The problem still persists. However I have found that this "overscrolling" only happens when scrolling with either the touchpad or the touchscreen on my laptop, not when I use a mouse. So it definetly is some laptop/touchscreen specific thing.

Also, I just checked and it does NOT happen on mobile, so it's definitely some Windows shenanigans. Thank you for the help!

Edit: and only in Firefox